# Little number for reviews available, but I've used up my 20/day

Tags: bug, review

Okay, so today I burnt out all of my 20 reviews per day on all of the categories (except Late Answers).  Then I go back to my answering work.  And then I notice that the little orange number in the corner for reviews that are available for me to do has a "6" on it.  And I am excited that I will be able to reach my 20 review limit in *all* the categories.  But when I click on it, to my dismay, it was telling me that these "available" reviews are not available because they are in a category that I have already done my limit!

So, shouldn't the number next to the review button not show me the numbers for the review categories that are no longer available to me?

It's just holding them in front of my face saying "Look at all the reviews that you *can't* do!".

Is there a reason that this isn't changed?